# two or more views in one layout (cakephp)

Tags: layout, view, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to add two or more views in one layout in cakephp 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

What you might need are elements: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements

you can put all info data in one element and then include it wherever you want.

view:

```
<div class="info">
    <h2><?php echo __('Info'); ?></h2>
    <?php echo $this->Element('info'); ?>
</div>
```

view/elements/info.ctp:

```
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
```